# Plotting Address on Virtual Earth

Tags: maps, virtual-earth

How can I plot a point of an address on a map?

I want to basically use VEMap.Find(), but simply get the coordinates of the location.

Answer (score 1):

When you call Find(), pass in true for the showResults parameter. The Microsoft doc has an example of how to do this:  [Microsoft's VEMap.Find() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429645.aspx)

If you really only want the lat/long of a result returned from VEMap.Find(), check out this blog post:  [Getting Coordinates from VEMap.Find()](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtualearth/archive/2008/04/08/geocoding-with-virtual-earth.aspx). The coordinates are accessible in the GetCoordinates function as properties of the findPlaceResults object.